retryCountOnTaskFailure with condition
background: I have an E2E task that it usually take 45 minutes, but sometimes the dev server fails to start (issue reported in Angular repo, no solution available yet and it seems few years old issue) and so the E2E fails after 2-3 minutes
what I want to do: make the E2E to retry using retryCountOnTaskFailure but only if the dev server fail to start (which happens in the first 5 minutes) but if the real test failed not to retry
there are two conditions I can use either of them, but I don't know how to add them to the azure.yml file

if the error contains Error: Web server failed to start in 300000ms. This can be configured in cypress.config.ts.
if the task failed before 5 minutes

my question how to write either one of these conditions
current setup
  - job: Cypress_Tests
    timeoutInMinutes: 120
    pool:
      vmImage: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - task: NodeTool@0
        inputs:
          versionSpec: '20.x'
        displayName: 'Install Node.js'

      - powershell: |
          corepack enable
          yarn install --immutable
        displayName: 'install dependencies'

      - script: |
          sudo apt-get update
          sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libgbm-dev libnotify-dev libgconf-2-4 libnss3 libxss1 libasound2 libxtst6 xauth xvfb
        displayName: 'Cypress Dependencies for Linux'

      - powershell: |
          yarn cypress:ci
        displayName: 'Cypress Run'


Please provide the pipeline definition you want to extend.

@KrzysztofMadej I have updated the question and added the current setup

I am afraid that there is no out-of-box method can use retryCountOnTaskFailure based on the error message or task running time.
To meet your requirement, I suggest that you can n add a powershell task after the E2E task, and then run the Rest API(Timeline - Get) to traverse the error messages in the previous tasks.
Then, you can use the logging command to set the pipeline variable to determine if the E2E task needs to be rerun.
Finally, you need to add an additional E2E task after the powershell task to re-run the task based on condition.
Here is an example:
PowerShell script Sample:
$token = "$(PAT)"

$url="https://dev.azure.com/{Organizationname}/{ProjectNmae}/_apis/build/builds/$(build.buildID)/timeline?api-version=7.0"

$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))


$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Get -ContentType application/json

ForEach( $issues in $response.records.issues )
{
  if($issues.type -eq "error")
  {
    $errormessage = $issues.Message
    if($errormessage.Contains("Web server failed to start in 300000ms"))
    {
      echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=IsRequireRetry]true"
    }

  }
  
} 

Yaml Sample:
steps:

- task: E2E Task
  continueOnError: true

- powershell: |
   $token = "$(PAT)"
   
   $url="https://dev.azure.com/{OrganizationName}/{ProjectName}/_apis/build/builds/$(build.buildID)/timeline?api-version=7.0"
   
   $token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))
   
   
   $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Get -ContentType application/json
   
   ForEach( $issues in $response.records.issues )
   {
     if($issues.type -eq "error")
     {
       $errormessage = $issues.Message
       if($errormessage.Contains("Web server failed to start in 300000ms"))
       {
         echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=IsRequireRetry]true"
       }
   
     }
     
   } 
  displayName: 'Check Error'

- task: E2E Task
  condition: eq(variables['IsRequireRetry'], 'true')
  retryCountOnTaskFailure: 5

Note: You need to add continueOnError: true to the first E2E task.
Reuslt:
When the error in E2E task contains the string, it will re-run the task.

Or it will skip the re-run task.

